# How to automatically add many similar lines to a text file?

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose we want to write a text file containing

```
user001
user002
user003
....
user999
```

Is there any smart way to build it instead of writing a program? Of course it would be easy by writing a C program or an awk script.

I am trying to find some automatic way in vi/vim or in a shell to add lines containing a constant text pattern and the updated value of a counter.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Would "similar line" always indicate the string `user` followed by three digits (ranging from 1 to 999), or anything else that looks "similar"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for counter in {001..999}; do echo "user${counter}" >> outputfile; done
```

For vim, there's a good answer here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5600

Comment: @infosec-guy I can't really call it code/script, it's just shell interpretation. I can't think of a way to make this leaner. In any case, you also asked about `vi`, I found a good answer for that, added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of interesting ways to do this in a short amount of characters

### For `bash`:

```bash
echo user{000..999} | tr ' ' '\n' > file
```

or

```bash
seq 000 999 | sed 's/^/user/' > file
```

### For `vim`:

You could just invoke one of the `bash` solutions using `:r!`

```
:r!seq 000 999 | sed 's/^/user/'
```

You could also just run `seq` from vim, and prepend `"user"` to all the lines

```
:r!seq 000 999
:%s/^/user
```

[image: vim: animated gif of the above solution]

or do it in a completely `vim`-native way:

- generate a 1000 lines containing just "user000": <kbd>i</kbd> `user000` <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>
- select all text: <kbd>gg</kbd><kbd>ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>
- tell vim to increment them one by one: <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>ctrl-a</kbd>

[image: vim: second animated gif of the above solution]

Answer (score 2):

A `bash` one-liner, without using an explicit loop nor an external utility:

```
printf 'user%s\n' {001..999} >> outputfile
```

This uses `printf`'s implicit loop and requires `bash` version 4.0 or newer (for leading zeros in brace expansions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use loops in shell. If you just paste this snippet into your terminal and press enter, it will create the file at your current location:

```bash
for i in {1..999}; do echo $(printf "user%03d" $i) >> test.txt; done
```

the loop iterates the variable `i`. Note that it's not enough to just concatenate `"user"` with `i` because we need leading `0`s. Thus we need to format the number with `%03d`, meaning it is a decimal that contains at least 3 digits. A number smaller than 100 will be prefixed with `0`s. With `source >> target` you can take the result from the `echo` command and write it into the file.

Comment: this reaches the goal but I was trying not to use any code/script

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on this part from your question: "I am trying to find some automatic way in vi/vim or in a shell to add lines".
My and all the other answers I see to your question work in a way, where you only have to paste these commands into an opened shell-terminal. You don't need to save it into a script file.
What where you searching for regarding "in a shell to add lines"?

Answer (score 0):

if you have `jot` by any chance, use it instead - i like it more than `seq` :

> ```
> jot -w 'user%.3d' 7
> ```

```
user001
user002
user003
user004
user005
user006
user007
```

> ```
> jot -s':' -w 'user%.3d' 7
> ```

```
user001:user002:user003:user004:user005:user006:user007
```

it can also do custom starrt/end points, and step size, similar to a typical `slice()` :

> ```
> jot -s$'\f' -w 'user%.3d' - 19 71 11
> ```

```
user019
       user030
              user041
                     user052
                            user063
```

or even individual bytes (although this example is silly) :

> ```
> jot -w 'user/ %c /grp' - 55 68
> ```

```
user/ 7 /grp
user/ 8 /grp
user/ 9 /grp
user/ : /grp
user/ ; /grp
user/ < /grp
user/ = /grp
user/ > /grp
user/ ? /grp
user/ @ /grp
user/ A /grp
user/ B /grp
user/ C /grp
user/ D /grp
```